# aws iptables nat works on eth0 but not on eth1

Tags: amazon-web-services, iptables

I have a very simple setup:  two t2.micro instances, one with eth0, and the other with eth0 and eth1, both in the same VPC with a 10.0.0.0/24 subnet in 10.0.0.0/16.

All I'm trying to do is have traffic from the internet routed through one t2 into the other, and return.

Here is the test setup, followed by what works, then by what does not work.  I need to make the second scenario work, and can't figure out how.

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward = 1

t2-A:  eth0 private IP 10.0.0.120 EIP a0.b0.c0.d0
       eth1 private IP 10.0.0.16  EIP a1.b1.c1.d1

t2-B:  eth0 private IP 10.0.0.113
```

I can ping a0.b0.c0.d0, the pings come in to 10.0.0.120, are NATed and routed to 10.0.0.113, and the ping replies come back out a0.b0.c0.d0 to me.

All it takes is these two rules:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p icmp -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.113
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p icmp -j MASQUERADE
```

But if I try to do the same thing through eth1, I can't get it to work:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth1 -p icmp -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.113
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth1 -p icmp -j MASQUERADE
```

Ping a1.b1.c1.d1 does not work.  I can see the pings hitting 10.0.0.16, and nothing else happens after that.  The pings never show up on 10.0.0.113 or any other interface, so of course ping replies are not sent.

When I first ran into this, I opened an aws support ticket, and they suggested it was an asymmetrical routing issue, and told me to do the following, something about policy-based routing:

```
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 table 1
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 table 2
ip rule add from 10.0.0.120/32 table 1 priority 500
ip rule add from 10.0.0.16/32 table 2 priority 600
```

I did that, but it had no effect at all on the problem.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Submitted this exact question to AWS Support.  They said they were able to reproduce the problem, said it is an AWS problem, but they have no solution at this time.  They did not say whether they were going  to submit an internal bug  on it.  So we will move ahead using eth0 as the NAT interface, since that is the only one that works.